# How come this loop is not working?

Tags: posts, loop

I've wrapped the contents of the loop within two `divs`.  However, only the **first** post appears to be wrapped within the `divs`, leaving the latter unstyled.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="inner_box"> 
            <ul>
                <?php
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <li>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); //this is not in inner_box ?> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Would anyone know why this is?

Comment: are you want each post inside `<div class="inner_box">`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner_box"> 
        <ul>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); //this is not in inner_box ?> 
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

try this

```
<div class="container"> 
    <ul>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <div class="inner_box">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); //this is not in inner_box ?>
                </div>   
            </li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to merge two posts into one `inner_box`. Is there a way to keep separate posts in two separate `inner_box`?

Comment: try to move inner_box inside li

Comment: Nope, still not working :(

Comment: When I remove the `li` completely, it seems to only load the latest post within the div.

Comment: have you tried with my second code?

Comment: Ah fixed it. Everything should've been *inside* the loop. Thanks for your help :)